# Multiple Serial Communications over USB between Arduino and RaspberryPI

Tags: python, mysql, linux, arduino, serial-communication

I have some problems with the communcation between my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and multiple (4) Arduino Nanos (ATmega328) with serial communication over USB. 
At the moment I connected 2-3 DS18B20 temperature sensors to each Arduino. I want to increase that amount to 10 per Arduino, when the rest is arriving.

Thats why I am using a USB HUB (EasyAcc USB 2.0 7 Ports Hub). I have no Idea why, but only 2 out of 7 Ports are working with the RaspberryPi.

The Arduino is collecting the Data from the sensors until he asked every sensor, then he prints the necessary data (specificid and temperature of each sensor) on the Serial communcation line.

The RaspberryPi is waiting curiously for this data. When he gets the Data he is editing the data so he can write it in my mysql databank. 
When I just connect one Arduino or just execute one python script for one Arduino it is working really fine.

The problem starts, when I connect more Arduinos (4 --> 2 at the USB HUB and 2 at the Raspberry).

When I do so, I use a Shell Skript to start the Python-programs in the background. For some seconds the RaspberryPi still execute all 4 Python Scripts (checked with "pidof python"). Then (I think when the first data arrives) all programs except one are stopping. 
In the errorlog is following text written:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/var/www/html/arduino0.py", line 19, in <module>
    if (ser0.inWaiting() > 3):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 435, in i$
    s = fcntl.ioctl(self.fd, TIOCINQ, TIOCM_zero_str)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

My first idea was, that the Raspberry is getting confused because I named every Serial variable "ser", so i changed them to ser0-ser3 and the same error popped up. To be honest I have no idea left.

That's why i'm asking you^^ I hope someone has an idea how to solve that problem.

Many thanks in advance!

Kind regards Ole

Arduino code:

```
    /* DS18S20 Temperature Sensor Module sample project with 4 Digit 7-Segment
*/
#include <OneWire.h>
int inPin=10; // define D10 as input pin connecting to DS18S20 S pin
OneWire ds(inPin);
int zahler=0;
String senddata = "";
int sensorcount = 3; //number of connected sensors 
void setup(void) {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(void) {
  int HighByte, LowByte, TReading, SignBit, Tc_100, Whole, Fract, Fracts;
  byte i;
  byte present = 0;
  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8]; 
  String stringadresse;
  if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
      ds.reset_search();
      return;
  }

  ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0x44,1); 

  delay(9800);  


  present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);    
  ds.write(0xBE);  



  for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) { 
    data[i] = ds.read();
  }
  LowByte = data[0];
  HighByte = data[1];
  TReading = (HighByte << 8) + LowByte;
  SignBit = TReading & 0x8000;  
  if (SignBit)
  {
    TReading = (TReading ^ 0xffff) + 1;
  }
  Tc_100 = (6 * TReading) + TReading / 4; 
  Whole = Tc_100 / 100;
  Fract = Tc_100 % 100; 
  Fracts = Fract / 10;
  if (SignBit)
  {
     Serial.print("-");
  }
  for ( i = 0; i < 8 ; i++){
    stringadresse = String(addr[i], HEX);
    senddata.concat(stringadresse); 
    if(i!=7){
    //Serial.print("-");
    }
  }

  senddata.concat("|");
  senddata.concat(Whole);
  senddata.concat(".");
  if (Fract < 10)
  {
    senddata.concat("0");
  }
  zahler++;
  senddata.concat(Fract);
   if(zahler != sensorcount){
    senddata.concat("-");
    }

  //Serial.print(zahler);
  if(zahler == sensorcount){
    zahler = 0;
    Serial.print(senddata);
    senddata = "";
    }
}
```

Python Code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb as mdb
import sys
import serial

con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'censored', 'censored', 'history');

ser0 = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", 9600) //USB0-USB3 and ser0-ser3
ser0.flushInput() //ser0-ser3 (<--- in the whole code)
ser0.timeout = 1
specificid = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
svalue = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
sensorid = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


while 1:
    if (ser0.inWaiting() > 3):
        text = ser0.readline()
        print "Folgender Text wurde vom Arduino empfangen: {}".format(text)
        splittext = text.split("-")
        i = 0
        print len(splittext)
        while i < len(splittext):
            splittext[i]=splittext[i].split("|")
            specificid[i] = splittext[i][0]
            svalue[i] = splittext[i][1]
            print "Spezifische Sensorid: {}".format(specificid[i])
            print "Temperatur: {}".format(svalue[i])
            with con:
                cur = con.cursor()
                cur.execute("SELECT sensorid FROM sensors WHERE sensorspecificid = %s",(specificid[i]))
                sensorid[i] = cur.fetchone()
                print "Eine Temperatur von {} wurde für den {}. Sensor in die Datenbank eingetragen".format(svalue[i],sensorid[i][0])
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO svalues(sensorid,value) VALUES(%s, %s)",(sensorid[i][0], svalue[i]))
            i = i +1
ser0.close()
```

Shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup python arduino0.py parameter > output0.txt 2> output0.txt &
nohup python arduino1.py parameter > output1.txt 2> output1.txt &
nohup python arduino2.py parameter > output2.txt 2> output2.txt &
nohup python arduino3.py parameter > output3.txt 2> output3.txt &
```

Comment: Anything in syslog? Or from something like `$ dmesg | tail -n 100`?

Comment: This is coming as error, when I use a wrong USB-Hub Port.
I am already looking for explantations.
[52096.297922] usb 1-1.4.4.3: new full-speed USB device number 52 using dwc_otg
[52096.377916] usb 1-1.4.4.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32